# Custom xylophone sticks?

Tags: xylophone

I just bought a second hand xylophone - without sticks. (It was just under $9...) So I wonder, what can I use as a substitute? Right now, I can't get to a music store but I in a few weeks I can, if that is necessary. But for now, anything someone may have at home that works?

EDIT: The bars are made in metal. Maybe it's a metallophone...?

Comment: Hmm.  Stale marshmallows on a stick?  Or wrap cotton balls with electrical tape?  Basically I'm thinking soft, but not too much so.  Oh -- and is it wood or metal?  In the former case my suggestions may be no good.

Comment: @MatthewRead It's metal. But it doesn't really sound much - I tried a round stick, pretty much no sound. Am I supposed to use something really soft or really hard?

Comment: If it's metal, it's not a xylophone. Xylo = wood. More likely to be a glockenspiel.Try the internet. Not much that can't be found to buy there.Hard rubber ends on sticks work best.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, probably a glockenspiel. Looks exactly like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Glockenspiel.jpg but it's slightly bigger.

Comment: Use a bow! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU290O2BjKg

Answer (score 2):

If you have any small hard rubber balls especially the kind that used to be called Super Balls which bounce very high you can mount those on chopsticks or drum sticks. Drill the holes a little smaller than the diameter of the sticks and try using epoxy, super glue or hot glue to fix them.